# Long words/code blocks breaking responsive design

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I often browse JSE on my smartphone (Lumia 920), and although the mobile version works fine, some of the posts are impossible to read due to long URLs and code blocks expanding the viewport beyond the screen. Here's a screenshot from  a random [answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/proper-folder-structure-for-custom-component/4260#4260) that causes this problem:

[image: JSE on Windows Phone 8.1]

Parts of the text is cut of, and without scroll bars it just can't be read. Zooming is not possible either.

I don't know if this problem is specific to Windows Phone (unable to test on Android/IOS at the moment), but it makes many posts impossible to read on a small screen.